# Any benefit to explicitly dropping local temporary tables at the end of a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following psuedo T-SQL code (performed by a stored procedure):

```
CREATE TABLE #localTable ...

<do something with the temporary table here>

DROP TABLE #localTable;
```

The `DROP TABLE` statement is the last statement executed by the stored proceudre – is there any benefit to that statement?

Note that I'm not asking about dropping temporary tables (local or not) in the *middle* of the stored procedure (i.e. after the tables are no longer needed, but before the end of the stored procedure code) – that could seemingly have important benefits due to decreasing the memory required to continue executing the stored procedure. I want to know whether there's any benefit (or any effect, really, positive *or* negative) to explicitly dropping the table versus 'letting' SQL Server do so when the stored procedure finishes executing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Won't hurt to do so, but the table gets dropped when the connection is dropped. I personally think it's a good habit to get into. It also lets developers, who might have to work on this, that you didn't simply forget to do it.

Comment: The table won't be dropped when the stored procedure completes?

Comment: @Kenny - I believe temporary tables are tied to a connection. So when the connection is dropped, temp tables are dropped.

Comment: @RandyMinder - This is only the case if they are created at the top level scope. If created in a child scope (such as a procedure call) they are cleaned up automatically as the scope exits. For a procedure cleaning up will be dropping if the table isn't cached  or as per rageit's answer otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

Theres a good detailed post on this [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20180130201242/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx).

> The temporary object is renamed to an internal form when DROP TABLE is executed, and renamed back to the same user-visible name when CREATE TABLE is encountered on the next execution.  In addition, any statistics that were auto-created on the temporary table are also cached.  This means that statistics from a previous execution remain when the procedure is next called.

Comment: That post by Paul White is fantastic!

Comment: Wow, that post is insanely good, I had no idea that temp tables were cached in that way and I have been coding in SQL for almost 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping Temp table is a good habit
otherwise that consume space in TEMP DB after our operation.

That will cause space issue .
This will get cleared only you shrink TEMP DB or restart the server.

Comment: But temporary tables created in a stored procedure are automatically dropped when the procedure finishes executing and the relevant connection is closed. Dropping a temp table created in a stored procedure should only affect the timing of reclaiming any space it uses and, in most cases, probably not by much.

Comment: but the connection is properly closed then ??