# use pivot table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot-table, temp-tables

I have a pivot query that works great!

```
;with PivotData As (
Select KeyField, ColumnName, FieldValue FROM
(SELECT SomeField as KeyField, NameField As ColumnName, DataField as FieldValue
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT SomeField, NameField, DataField
FROM Table2)
SELECT [List of Fields] FROM PivotData
PIVOT (Max(PivotData.FieldValue) for ColumnName In ([List of Fields])) As P
```

Now I want to use that query as the source of a temp table in a stored procedure and none of the syntax that I have tried to INSERT the results of the query into a temp table have worked.

Can I create a temporary table from the results?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Leslie

Comment: What exactly do you need temp tbl for? As an intermediate recordset inside SP or to feed it with SP resultset? Or to fill it inside SP?

Comment: I need to run a series of queries on the data returned in order to determine if a record should be inserted in a table in the database.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Where is the temp table in that process?

Comment: When I start the stored procedure I need to run my pivot query and then run 15 different queries and set a boolean if any conditions are met.  At the end of the stored procedure if the boolean is false I don't insert a record.

Comment: Leslie, I wanted to know what do you fill into temp table. I will assume that you fill result of your pivot query. So, you have to (1) create #temp table, (2) fill #temp with pivot data, (3-1) run query1 and update #temp.myFlag according to that, (3-2) run query2 and update #temp.myFlag according to that, ... (3-15) run query15 and update #temp.myFlag according to that; (4) insert into destinationTbl (...) select ... from #temp where myFlag = 1; HTH

Comment: No I am doing just what Sonam posted: SELECT [LIST OF FIELDS] INTO #TEMP FROM PivotData which runs my query and creates the temp table.  It's all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
;with PivotData As (
Select KeyField, ColumnName, FieldValue FROM
(SELECT SomeField as KeyField, NameField As ColumnName, DataField as FieldValue
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT SomeField, NameField, DataField
FROM Table2)
SELECT [List of Fields] into #temp FROM PivotData
PIVOT (Max(PivotData.FieldValue) for ColumnName In ([List of Fields])) As P
```

here you dont have to declare a table or table variable specifically for the purpose.

Comment: Don't forget to delete the temp table at the end of the stored procedure! In addition, the syntax for this is incorrect.

Comment: @JoeFletch: what temporary table? Btw temp tbls get shredded when SP exits.

Comment: I figured it out about 5 minutes after I posted!  Isn't that the way it usually works!

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić, `#temp`, no? Otherwise the next time that you run the Stored Procedure, the `SELECT ... INTO #temp` will fail.

Comment: @JoeFletch: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670924/any-benefit-to-explicitly-dropping-local-temporary-tables-at-the-end-of-a-stored)

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić, thanks for sharing that link. Now I have more research to do on the topic!